# How to make Bootstrap carousel slider for Mobile version of site?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I was able to find the solution on here that seems pretty straightforward by using BCSwipe: https://github.com/maaaaark/bcSwipe.

I followed the instruction however, when I try to implement it, nothing happens.

I am using and still fairly new to ColdFusion. However, I figure if I did the following to implement the script, like in the BCSwipe instructions, I would be able to swipe the carousel on my phone:

```
 <cfscript>
    $('.carouselSwipe').bcSwipe({ threshold: 50 });
</cfscript>
```

However, it throws an error that the '$' is not recognized and not sure how to go from there.

The following is the Bootstrap Carousel and where I put the '.carouselSwipe' in:

```js
     $('.carouselSwipe').bcSwipe({ threshold: 50 });
```

```html
<cffunction name="dspCarouselByFeedName" output="false">
  <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="Slideshow" />
  <cfargument name="showCaption" type="boolean" default="true" />
  <cfargument name="cssID" type="string" default="myCarousel" />
  <cfargument name="size" type="string" default="custom" hint="If you want to use a custom height/width, then use 'custom' ... otherwise, you can use 'small, medium, large' OR any other predefined custom image size 'name' you created via the back-end administrator." />
  <cfargument name="width" type="numeric" default="1280" hint="width in pixels" />
  <cfargument name="height" type="numeric" default="500" hint="height in pixels" />
  <cfargument name="interval" type="any" default="5000" hint="Use either milliseconds OR use 'false' to NOT auto-advance to next slide." />
  <cfargument name="autoStart" type="boolean" default="true" />
  <cfargument name="showIndicators" type="boolean" default="true" />
  <cfscript>
   var local = {};
   local.imageArgs = {};

   if ( not ListFindNoCase('small,medium,large,custom', arguments.size) and variables.$.getBean('imageSize').loadBy(name=arguments.size,siteID=variables.$.event('siteID')).getIsNew() ) {
    arguments.size = 'custom';
   };

   if ( not Len(Trim(arguments.size)) or LCase(arguments.size) eq 'custom' ) {
    local.imageArgs.width = Val(arguments.width);
    local.imageArgs.height = Val(arguments.height);
   } else {
    local.imageArgs.size = arguments.size;
   };
  </cfscript>
  <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
  <cfoutput>
   <!--- BEGIN: Bootstrap Carousel --->
   <!--- IMPORTANT: This will only output items that have associated images --->
   <cfset local.feed = variables.$.getBean('feed').loadBy(name=arguments.feedName)>
   <cfset local.iterator = local.feed.getIterator()>
   <cfif local.feed.getIsNew()>
    <div class="container carouselSwipe">
     <div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
      <h4>Ooops!</h4>
      The <strong>#HTMLEditFormat(arguments.feedName)#</strong> Content Collection/Local Index does not exist.
     </div>
    </div>
   <cfelseif local.iterator.hasNext()>
    <div id="#arguments.cssID#" class="carousel slide" data-interval="#arguments.interval#">

     <!--- Indicators --->
     <cfif arguments.showIndicators>
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
       <cfset local.iterator.reset()>
       <cfset local.idx = 0>
       <cfloop condition="local.iterator.hasNext()">
        <cfset local.item=iterator.next()>
        <cfif ListFindNoCase('jpg,jpeg,gif,png', ListLast(local.item.getImageURL(), '.'))>
         <li data-target="###arguments.cssID#" data-slide-to="#idx#" class="<cfif local.idx eq 0>active</cfif>"></li>
         <cfset local.idx++>
        </cfif>
       </cfloop>
      </ol>
     </cfif>

     <!--- Wrapper for slides --->
     <div class="row carousel-inner">
      <cfset local.iterator.reset()>
      <cfset local.idx = 0>
      <cfloop condition="local.iterator.hasNext()">
       <cfset local.item=iterator.next()>
       <cfif ListFindNoCase('jpg,jpeg,gif,png', ListLast(local.item.getImageURL(), '.'))>
        <div class="row item<cfif local.idx eq 0> active</cfif>">
         <img src="#local.item.getImageURL(argumentCollection=local.imageArgs)#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#">
         <cfif arguments.showCaption>
          <div class="container">
           <div class="carousel-caption">
               <div>
            <!--- <h3><a href="#local.item.getURL()#">#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#</a></h3> --->
            <div class="visible-xs"><!---<h2>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#</h2>---></div>
             <div class="hidden-xs">#local.item.getSummary()#
             <!--- #local.item.getBody()# --->
             <!---<p><a class="btn btn-larg btn-primary" href="#local.item.getURL()#">Read More</a></p>--->
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </cfif>
        </div>
        <cfset local.idx++>
       </cfif>
      </cfloop>
     </div>

     <cfif local.idx>
      <!--- Controls --->
      <cfif local.idx gt 1>
       <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="###arguments.cssID#" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
       <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="###arguments.cssID#" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
       <!--- AutoStart --->
       <cfif arguments.autoStart>
        <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('###arguments.cssID#').carousel({interval:#arguments.interval#});});</script>
       </cfif>
      </cfif>
     <cfelse>
      <div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
       <h4>Oh snap!</h4>
       Your feed has no items <em>with images</em>.
      </div>
     </cfif>
    </div>
   <cfelse>
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-block">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
     <h4>Heads up!</h4>
     Your feed has no items.
    </div>
   </cfif>
   <!--- // END: Bootstrap Carousel --->
  </cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
  <cfreturn local.str />
 </cffunction>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The `$` in JavaScript is typically a reference for jQuery. Is the jQuery file being loaded before your script is run on the page? Open up your browser's developer tools and then navigate to the page. It will give you a lot more information about what is going on.

Comment: @Miguel-F Yes, it is being loaded before the script is going to be run on the page. I run the console on developer tools and it appears the file failed to load. However, when I go to resources it shows but it is blanked. Do not know why that is the case

Comment: The following is what I added to the head tag: <script src="#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/js/jquery.bcSwipe"></script>
 <script src="#$.siteConfig('assetPath')#/js/jquery.bcSwipe.min.js"></script> I added the script above the cfoutput

Comment: You don't need to include both of those files. One is simply a minified version of the other. Just include the `jquery.bcSwipe.min.js` file. Do you see any 404 errors for the javascript files? Make sure you can access them at that address.

Comment: Don't forget to include jquery.js

Comment: @Miguel-F You are correct, I just need include one of them which I have and yet it doesn't work and the 404 error does not appear. To Bernhard, jquery.js is included in the file.

Comment: Says there is an error on line 49: this.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove); which I dont get why

Comment: Your first code snippet should be wrapped in a `<script>` tag, not a `<cfscript>` tag.

Comment: Order matters too. The jQuery file has to be loaded before the bcSwipe file. It looks like you are using Mura so there is much more going on here. Check the HTML output after loading the page and verify where/when the JavaScript files are being loaded.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten yes you are correct, it would be script tag. However, I am in coldfusion and they have there own tags and so I am using cfscript

Comment: @Miguel-F I will look into that. I will see if that will change anything, thank you for letting me know

Comment: @RobertoFlores the `cfscript` tag is for the ColdFusion server to process code. You need to use `<script>` tags for JavaScript which this code is `$('.carouselSwipe').bcSwipe({ threshold: 50 });`.

Comment: You only need to use `<cfscript>` tags if you are mixing CFML script syntax inside of tag syntax. It doesn't appear to be the case here - you only have JavaScript inside the `<cfscript>` tag. The JavaScript won't run properly if not wrapped in a `<script>` tag, as the browser won't know what to do with it.

Comment: @CarlVonStetten Thank you for the explanation. I will try that

Comment: @CarlVonStetten Did not work. I reorder the which js goes first, change the cfscript to script tags and it didnt work. Not sure what is going on